# Enabling Xdebug in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have installed Xdebug in my Paragon server and I am trying to enable it in PhpStorm. But when I follow the steps I am unable to correctly validate the installation.

I have updated my php.ini file inside my php installation directory to the new version of Xdebug 3.0:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = C:\Laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.13-Win32-vc15-x64\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.0-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9000
```

But I still keep on getting the validation errors in PhpStorm. I have also installed the Chrome extension for Xdebug, but I cannot seem to get it to work with PhpStorm.

[image]

Comment: What's your PhpStorm version?

Comment: @LazyOne I currently have version 2020.2 installed.

Comment: Will work also with previous versions (tested with 2002.2.4). Port changed from 9000 to 9003. Use custom values and add xdebug.client_host=<windows-ipv4> and xdebug.mode=debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xdebug 3 will be fully supported in PhpStorm **2020.3 version only**, which currently has a RC build and will be released in next few days.

It is already supported since EAP #6 build: check this blog post for more info: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/11/phpstorm-2020-3-eap-6/

---

**In PhpStorm 2002.2 and older** you may just skip/ignore such Validation. It's there for info purposes only anyway (as it does not guarantee that the debug connection will actually work (e.g. due to firewall or other network related issues that this validation check does not check)).

---

**P.S.** Here is how that Validation screen looks in **2020.3 RC** build for Xdebug 3 (PHP 8.0 here):

[image]

The same but when Xdebug 2.9.8 is used (PHP 7.3 where I still keep Xdebug 2):

[image]