# How can I connect Xdebug 3 to PhpStorm on Windows 10?

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to connect PhpStorm and debug PHP scripts/webpages with Xdebug, something I've done several times.

This is my php.ini file (the interesting bit):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

I set multiple breakpoints and called `xdebug_break()` on my index but code execution is not stopping at them.

This is the PhpStorm validation script output for Xdebug:
[image: This is the PhpStorm validation script output for Xdebug]

The output of netstat which shows that PhpStorm is listening on port 10000:
[image: The output of netstat which shows that PhpStorm is listening on port 10000]

Comment: Are you using decoupled site. meaning you have a separated front and separated restfull API? Or you are using the old way of server side rendering?

Comment: You are using Xdebug v3 ... but still using Xdebug v2 config parameters. Just use correct v3 parameter names: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: *"...and called `xdebug_break()` on my index...` Please note that `xdebug_break()` works differently in Xdebug 3: now it just acts as a breakpoint and will NOT initiate the debug session if it's not has been there already.

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, the debug session is initiated by phpstorm itself

Comment: Also, initially I tried with the v2 config parameters, but PhpStorm wasn't validating it and it wasn't working.

Comment: BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65091404/783119 -- Xdebug 3 will be fully supported in next 2020.3 version only. Debugging still works fine in 2020.2  (tested myself, on Windows with PHP 7.4 and 8.0).. but IDE will try to use Xdebug 2 params and hence these warnings from Xdebug.

Comment: @vladkatz I don't see how that is relevant, but yes, this is legacy code, so I'm not using a separated API.

Comment: @granitba So use Xdebug v3 param names and see what IDE has to say (taking my prev comments into the consideration).

Comment: @LazyOne I meant to say I tried with v3 params, but didn't test it when I saw that it doesn't validate. With v3 param names, I can use breakpoints! I don't know if other features like profiling will work though

Comment: @grantiba it's rellevant since xdebug using cookies and if you are using separated  front and back, the back won't recognize the cookie since it's cross domain. had this problem before

Comment: @vladkatz Ah okay, didn't realize that. In any case, I got it working now, at least the breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the lines in the php.ini to

`xdebug.mode=debug`

and set the port on PhpStorm to listen on 9003 instead of 9000.

In xdebug v3 the default xdebug port was changed to 9003:
https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#Step-Debugging

Answer (score 3):

Change

from

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

into

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=10000
```