# How to configure Xdebug for JetBrains PhpStorm 2020.1?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

So, I was quite happily debugging my PHP code with PhpStorm - until Windows became severely corrupted ... and my backup regime turned out to not quite as good as I had thought (let that be a lesson to many of us :-( )

Here's the relevant part of my `php.ini`:

```
[PHP]

[Xdebug]

; ---- trying to follow PHP storm's advice

zend_extension = "e:\coding\Web_development\php\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_port = 9000
;xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.idekey="xdebug"

; ----------   previously worked 
;xdebug.remote_enable=1
;xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.remote_autostart=1
;xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
;xdebug.idekey="xdebug"
;xdebug.remote_log=m:\xdebug.log
;xdebug.profiler_enable=0
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
;;xdebug.profiler_output_dir="F:\DropBox\programs\xampp\htdocs\_PHP_profile"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s.%t
```

And, here's what PhpStorm says :

[image]

***BUT*** much of that does not actually exist at https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings - as if some of those settings are no longer relevant/supported.

So, can anyone post the relevant `[Xdebug]` portion of `php.ini` for PHP storm 2020.1 ?

Comment: Please READ what the message says. And it says: *"This settings has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.rog/docs/upgrade_guide "*. In short: you are using Xdebug **v3**, it uses DIFFERENT settings than Xdebug v2. You just need to check the upgrade guide and replace certain config params by another (different names).

Comment: 2nd note: Xdebug 3 is supported since 2020.3. It still will wok with previous versions, no issues ... but Xdebug will complain on old (v2) params that IDE sends + PhpStorm will be showing similar screen (as it checks v2 params only).

Comment: Related questions/answers (that I did): https://stackoverflow.com/a/65091404/783119 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141934/783119.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upgrade that's catching you out here is not PhpStorm, it's XDebug: XDebug 3.0 [came out a couple of weeks ago](https://xdebug.org/announcements/2020-11-25), and has completely overhauled the settings. As mentioned in one of the messages in your screenshot [there is an upgrade guide on the XDebug site](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide)

It looks like PhpStorm's checking script isn't fully updated yet, so it's recommending a confusing mixture of old and new settings.

The most important changes are:

- The new `xdebug.mode` setting toggles a whole bunch of settings at once rather than having to remember the right combination. Some settings are simply no longer needed because of this.
- The default port is now 9003 instead of 9000, because of some other popular software using the same port.
- A lot of remaining settings have been renamed to be clearer.

Looking down your old config:

```ini
zend_extension = "e:\coding\Web_development\php\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
   ; this tells PHP to load the XDebug extension
   ; note that the file name includes the version number, confirming that you're using v3
xdebug.remote_enable=1 
   ; now implied by xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 
   ; renamed xdebug.client_host
xdebug.remote_port=9000 
   ; renamed xdebug.client_port
   ; also, the default is now 9003 not 9000
   ; so either set to 9000 here, or tell PhpStorm to use port 9003
xdebug.remote_autostart=1 
   ; replaced with xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
   ; no longer needed, as there was only one valid value
xdebug.idekey="xdebug" 
   ; still supported, but not usually needed
xdebug.remote_log=m:\xdebug.log 
   ; replaced by xdebug.log
xdebug.profiler_enable=0 
   ; now implied by xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0 
   ; now implied by xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="F:\DropBox\programs\xampp\htdocs\_PHP_profile" 
   ; not needed for debugging
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s.%t 
   ; not needed for debugging
```

So your new config should I believe look like this:

```ini
zend_extension = "e:\coding\Web_development\php\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9000 ; or 9003, but should match the setting in PhpStorm
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey="xdebug"
xdebug.log=m:\xdebug.log
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this. It is `bed-time o'clock` over here, but I will sort this out in the morning & award the answer. This excellent answer ought to help other future readers of this question. Stay healthy

Comment: @IMSoP You should use `lang-ini` instead of `ini` if you want to see syntax colors for those code blocks. Apparently `lang-` prefix is needed for `ini` syntax highligter

Comment: Shoudl I also remove `zend_extension` ? When I do so, I get "no debug extension is loaded", butif I leave it out I still get some of the same old errors.

Comment: This [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091219/enabling-xdebug-in-phpstorm/65091404#65091404) says "`Xdebug 3 will be fully supported in PhpStorm 2020.3 version only, which currently has a RC build and will be released in next few days`"

Comment: Aha! Maybe if I backgrade to Xdebug v2 ?

Comment: Nvm, I upgraded to PHP dtorm 2020.3 and now it works ! Thankses

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even know that validation check existed; it's certainly not necessary for that to pass for XDebug to work, so I would have gone with "ignore it and see if the instructions in the migration guide work".

Comment: @LazyOne Ah, thanks; that seems like a bug in the new markdown integration, but whatever, it looks much better now :)

Comment: @IMSoP OMG! just tested with port 9003 and because that did NOT work either, I tried something new; seems I need to restart Apache each time I change `php.ini` (or at least Xdebug settings).

Comment: @Top-Master Ah, yes, easily done - if you're running PHP as an Apache module, it only reads php.ini when Apache restarts.